# Using Custom Tags and JSP with AJAX functionality

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, custom-tag

I am developing a simple web application in which a web page accept a value from user through textfield and passes it to the custom tag which process that input string and prints the output

code is as follows

Index.jsp

```
<body>
    <form action="Result.jsp" >
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2 align="center"><h1>Restricted Domain Names</h1></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Enter Domain:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtdomainname"></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2 align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Check4Sensitivity??"></td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </form>

</body>
```

Result.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/Whois" prefix="j"  %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Restricted Domain Names</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <td style="color: red;">
    ***<j:RestrictedDomainName></j:RestrictedDomainName>***
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

it works perfectly. but i want to display the form and output on the same page using ajax how can i do this using ajax on jsp page and using custom tags for business logic and displaying purpose

Thanks

Comment: There are lot of AJAX tutorials. I suggest you should start going through them.

Answer (score 1):

1.Add to Index.jsp javascrip library to use ajax, for example, jquery

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

2.Call ajax on submit

```js
function onFormSubmit() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'Result.jsp',
    dataType : "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        $('#somefield').val(data);
    }
});
```

3.Result.jsp must be like

```html
<%@ page contentType="application/json"  %>  
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/Whois" prefix="j"  %>  
<j:RestrictedDomainName></j:RestrictedDomainName>
```